# C# ASP.net How to add a reload of the page/panel at the end of a button event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, triggers, updatepanel

I have a page that consists of an updatepanel with a DropDownList, a textbox and a button in it. The updatepanel has a trigger for the button. This works fine for all my "error" cases, such as "No input!", when I pop an alert with
`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1, UpdatePanel1.GetType(),"noName", "window.onload = function(){alert('Please enter a username!');window.location ='Accounts.aspx';}", true);` and the like.

But when I don't hit the alerts and the button event runs all it should I seem to land in some dead zone. My alerts stop displaying even though the code runs (checked by debugging), the button event does still preform all tasks as it should. However, if I refresh the page I get the classic:
[To display webpage again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuEyI.jpg). After I click retry my "latest" message pops up and then it works just like on first load.

So, I'm guessing that the PostBackTrigger on my button triggers a PostBack before or during the event execution since when the event is done nothing more happens until I reload. I'm thinking I need to add a reload at the end of my button event. Therefore my question is: How do I add a reload of the page/panel at the end of a button event?

**Edit:**
Forgot to mention that when the button event runs all it should it edits the web.config file, if this somehow could cause my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem, by removing my triggers and instead using:

```
ScriptManager1.RegisterPostBackControl(Button);
```

Then I could also put an:

```
UpdatePanel1.Update();
```

At the end of my button event.